# Create ActiveX.DLL in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, activex

I am trying to create an ActiveX.DLL file.  I have created them before with VB 5.0.  However, I can't find this option in Visual Basic 2010.  Has it been renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create ActiveX objects in VB 2010. You will have to create a class library and use that instead.

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dsandor/activexinnet11102005040748am/activexinnet.aspx) is a guide for doing it with C#, but there is very little code and I am sure you will figure it out in no time.

Comment: Any examples using Visual Basic?